# How to compile cmake without glibcxx21 on CENTOS server

Tags: c++, cmake, centos

I am trying to compile mesa 17 on CENTOS7 cluster. It requires `llvm-config` which can only be built using CMake.

But CMake requires `libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21`. What can I do? 
I don't have root access.

Is there any way to compile mesa without `llvm-config` or to get `llvm-config` compiled files?
Is there a llvm version compatible with GLIBCXX_3.4.19?

Comment: Yo must have mesa-libOSMesa. So, you can dowload mesa-libOSMesa-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7 RPM, that is the last version I guess.

Comment: But i don't have root access so I am unable to run rpm to install package.

Comment: In that case you must add the source local  beside the code of the project.

Comment: But I am unable to compile the mesa source code. It requires llvm-config which requires GLIBCXX_3.4.21.